# run two animation simultaneously in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two animation with two different .xml files,one animation is of Translet and another is of frame by frame animation.I want to run both of these animation simultaneously in one activity.Can anyone tell me how can I do this...?

Comment: could I add AnimationDrawable in AnimationSet..?

Answer (score 4):

Use [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html). You can call **addAnimation(Animation a)** to add numbers of Animation as you wanted;

Answer (score 0):

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.youranim1,R.anim.youranim12);
```